# Filtering notices with redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

This is my notesSlice:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:8000/";

const initialState = {
  notices: [],
};

export const getNotices = createAsyncThunk(
  "notices/getNotices",
  async (_name, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const resp = await axios(`${url}notices`);
      return resp.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue("something went wrong");
    }
  }
);

const noticesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "notices",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    filterNotices: (state, { payload }) => {
      console.log(state.notices)
      console.log(payload)

      if (payload.searchOption === "Simple") {
        state.notices = state.notices.filter((note) =>
          note.title.toLowerCase().includes(payload.search.toLowerCase())
        );
      } else if (payload.searchOption === "Advanced") {
        state.notices = state.notices.filter(
          (note) =>
            note.description
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(payload.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            note.tags.filter((tag) => {
              tag.toLowerCase().includes(payload.search.toLowerCase());
            })
        );
      }
    },

  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getNotices.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.notices = payload;
      })
```

In payload of `filterNotice` method, I am sending object with `search` input and `searchOption`. How should I search through all notices every time I call `filterNotice` method? And is this even the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mutate your source of truth by filtering it. The filtered result should be computed/derived "state" from the `notices` state and the `search` value.

### If you don't need to persist the filtered notices

Store the search type and value in state and use selector functions to compute the derived state.

```js
const initialState = {
  notices: [],
  searchOption: "Simple",
  searchValue: "",
};
    
const noticesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "notices",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setSearch: (state, action) => {
      const { searchOption, search } = action.payload;
      state.searchOption = searchOption;
      state.searchValue = search.toLowerCase();
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
});

export const selectFilteredNotices = state => {
  const { notices, searchOption, searchValue } = state.path.to.notices;

  switch(searchOption) {
    case "Simple":
      return notices.filter((note) =>
        note.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
      );

    case "Advanced":
      return notices.filter((note) =>
        note.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
        note.tags.some((tag) => tag.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
      );

    default:
      return notices;
  }
};
```

The UI would dispatch the `setSearch` action to update the search value and use the `useSelector` hook and `selectFilteredNotices` function to selected the filtered notices value.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const filteredNotices = useSelector(selectFilteredNotices);

...

dispatch(setSearch({ searchOption, search }));
...
```

### If you do need to persist the filtered notices in state

Create a new `filteredNotices` array in state, and when dispatching the `filterNotices` action you will filter the untouched `state.notices` array and return/update the `state.filteredNotices` array. This leaves the original notices data intact.

```js
const initialState = {
  notices: [],
  filteredNotices: [],
};
    
const noticesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "notices",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    filterNotices: (state, action) => {
      const { searchOption, search } = action.payload;
      const searchValue = search.toLowerCase();

      if (searchOption === "Simple") {
        state.filteredNotices = state.notices.filter((note) =>
          note.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
        );
      } else if (searchOption === "Advanced") {
        state.filteredNotices = state.notices.filter((note) =>
          note.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
          note.tags.some((tag) => tag.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))
        );
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```